# Science Bowl Question Regarding Connecting Segments

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of 5 points, no 3 of which are collinear, how many different ways are there to use 5 segments to connect the 5 points in such a way that each point is an endpoint for exactly 2 of the segments?

Comment: The answer is 12, but I am unsure how to solve

Comment: What did you try? Add it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words, you have five beads. How many necklaces can be made from these five beads with the intuitive restrictions?

The number of ways of ordering five beads is $5!$. There is no start or end, so we've overcounted by counting $5$ different starting locations instead of $1$. For instance, $ABCDE$ is the same necklace as $BCDEA$. Also, we have overcounted by forgetting that we can go in both directions. So $ABCDE$ is the same necklace as $EDCBA$.

So there are $\dfrac{5!}{5\cdot 2} = 12$ different ways.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the points in the plane as vertices for a graph. You want a regular graph of degree $2$ These graphs are known to have cycles as connected components. In this case the only possibility is exactly one cycle of length five since if we where to have more than one cycle then one of the cycles would have length two or less, which is impossible.

How many cycles on vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5$ do we have? We can write each cycle as a sequence of vertices staring with $v_1$. There are $4!$ ways to order the four vertices after $v_1$. Of course we are counting each cycle twice since for example $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5$ produces the same cycle as $v_1,v_5,v_4,v_3,v_2$. So the answer is half of $4!$ which is $12$ as desired.